# How can I have my translator detect the morse code as a string, not a char

Tags: java

Here is my code. I am having an issue. It works just fine but when you convert morse code to english, it only prints out the morse code single digit letters. Can someone give me a solution or at least help me understand what is wrong because it is immensely frustrating.

Here is the bit of my code that matters

An example of the problem is when i put in `.-` it printed `e` and `t`, not `a`.

```
public class Project1
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    System.out.println();
    choice();

}
    public static void choice()
{
    int user_choice = 0; 
    user_choice = Input.getInt("Enter 1 if you want to change English to Morse code, and enter 2 to change Morse code to English");
    if(user_choice == 1)
    {
    String output = new String();
    String inital = new String();
    inital = english_to_morse();

    for( int k = 0; k < inital.length(); k++)
    {
        output += morse(inital.charAt( k ));
    }

        System.out.print(output);

    }
    if(user_choice == 2)
    {
    String output2 = new String();
    String inital2 = new String();
    inital2 = morse_to_english();

    for( int k = 0; k < inital2.length(); k++)
    {
        System.out.println("#####"+String.valueOf(inital2.charAt( k ))+"#####");
        output2 += english(String.valueOf(inital2.charAt( k )));
    }
        System.out.print(output2);
    }
}

public static String english_to_morse() 
{
  String user_input = new String();

  user_input = Input.getString("Enter a phrase and I'll convert it to Morse Code");

  return user_input.toLowerCase();
}

public static String morse_to_english() 
{
  String user_input = new String();

  user_input = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in Morse Code and I'll convert it to English");

  return user_input.toLowerCase();
}

public static String morse(char letter)
{
    String output = new String();
    char[] alphabet_numbers = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' ' };
    String morse_code[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|" };

    for( int j = 0; j < alphabet_numbers.length; j++ )
    {
        if (alphabet_numbers[j]==letter)
        {
            output = morse_code[j];
        }
    }
    return output + " ";
}   
public static String english(String letter)
{
    String output = new String();
    String alphabet_numbers[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", " " };
    String morse_code[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|" };

    for( int j = 0; j < morse_code.length; j++ )
    {
        if (morse_code[j].equals(letter))
        {
            output = alphabet_numbers[j];
        }
    }
    return output + " ";
}   
}
```

Comment: You should give an example of what result you get and what you expected

Comment: I put .- which is the letter "a". But, it printed "e t". E is represented in morse code by a single "." and t is represented by a single "-"

Comment: You're iterating over each character, not each group of characters. Java isn't going to automatically know how to read morse code.

Comment: In any case, your simple loop approach isn't going to work as it is given. When do you know when to stop consuming characters? If I read `-` do I stop and convert that? Or do I read `-.` and then convert it?

Comment: @user3474526 But your code does not print anything, so we don't really know how you're calling `english` here, and that seems to be the problem. Post the whole code, and write the example in the question as well

Comment: Following MxyL's statement, I'm not sure if `String morse_code[]` is the same as `String[] morse_code`, which may be what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano i put the whole code

Comment: are you sure? I've tested your code with input `.-` and it prints `a`.

Comment: @RafaEl that shouldn't be possible, since it's reading one character at a time and converting it. Granted I never RAN the code myself so experimental results is always more credible.

Comment: I tried it and it printed out "e" and "t" again

Comment: @RafaEl did you edit it?

Comment: no edit. which method actually doesn't work? I tried `english(".-")` output `a`. Well, you should post the full code earlier. -_-

Comment: @user3474526, I have removed my answer because they are correct that you definitely need a delimiter of some sort, or else the problem is ambiguous.

Comment: It seems like you only process one character at a time.  No way it can recognize more than one dot or dash at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Well the reason why `.-` is giving `et` instead of `a` is due to the way you're reading the string.

Your code reads `.` and then looks up the table to determine whether it corresponds to any alpha character, in which case it does: `e`. Then you read a `-` and you look it up and you get a `t`.

If your input is literally just

```
.-.---.-.-.........-----.-.-.-.-
```

You're pretty much stuck because you don't know when one ends and another begins. As another example, how should one distinguish between the following strings

```
.
..
...
....
```

They are all equally valid signals, but depending on how you interpret it, you get very different results.

You can't say something like "I'll just take the longest matching string" because there is no reason why that is a valid rule.

If the sample input I provided above does not match your input, you should indicate what your input is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you iterate your strings.

When going from English to Morse, it is ok to just iterate single characters as you do here:

```
for( int k = 0; k < inital.length(); k++) {
    output += morse(inital.charAt( k ));
}
```

but when going from Morse to English you have to iterate several characters at once, because a symbol in Morse generally spans several characters. For instance, the Morse string `.- -... -.-.` has three symbols that correspond to `abc` in English, but they have 2, 4 and 4 characters each.

So when iterating your Morse string, you have to split it by spaces, and iterate each of the substrings. In the case above, you'll iterate `.-`, then `-...` and then `-.-.`:

```
for(String symbol : inital2.split(" ")){
    output2 += english(symbol);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line

`output2 += english(String.valueOf(inital2.charAt( k )));`

You give ".-" as input, but it does not convert ".-", because it takes each character of the string ".-" and converts it, which gives your "e t" result.

To fix this you have to use a separator in your morse code input. You already somehow defined " " as a separator so I will use it.

`if(user_choice == 2){
    String output2 = new String();
    String[] inital2 = morse_to_english().split(" ");
    for( int k = 0; k < inital2.length; k++){
        output2 += english(inital2[k]);
    }
    System.out.print(output2);
}`

Comment: I would use a blank as a separator.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks no idea what I was thinking with the "|". Changed it.